# How get size_of $_GET

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, get, superglobals

I want to get the number of values that were submitted via my $_GET. I'm going to be using a for loop and every 7 are going to be saved to a class.  Does anyone know how to find the Size_of the $_GET array?  I looked through this info [$_GET Manual](http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.get.php), but don't see what I'm looking for.

This is a code snippet that I started in the class that I go to after the submit.

```
for($i=0;$i<$_GET<size>;$i++) {
    $ID = $_GET["ID"][$i];
    $Desc = $_GET["Desc"][$i];
    $Yevaluation = $_GET["Yevaluation"][$i];
    $Mevaluation = $_GET["Mevaluation"][$i];
    $Cevaluation = $_GET["Cevaluation"][$i];
    $Kevaluation = $_GET["Kevaluation"][$i];
    $comment = $_GET["comment"][$i];
    //saving bunch to class next
}
```

Comment: Hey, I'm new to php and I searched for size used with GET and it didn't turn up.  I'm not sure why that is, but your offensive remark didn't help. I think I'm doing pretty good considering the lack of anyone who knows php around here, so ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is an array. Like any other array in PHP, to find the number of elements in an array you can use [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) or its alias [`sizeof()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php).

Answer (score 2):

```
count($_GET["ID"])
```

could work. However, then you have to be sure that each index contains the same number of elements.

More secure would be

```
min(count($_GET["ID"]), count($_GET["Desc"]), ...)
```

With `array_map` this can probably be shortcut to something like:

```
min(array_map(count, $_GET))
```

Try thinking through the last one, if it seems difficult to you. It's called functional programming and it's an awesome way to shortcut some stuff. In fact `array_map` calls another function on each element of an array. It's actually the same as:

```
$filteredGet = array();
foreach ($element in $_GET) { // this is the array_map part
    $filteredGet[] = count($element);
}
min($filteredGet);
```

Even better would be a structure where `$i` is the first level of the array, but I think this is not possible (built-in) with PHPs `$_GET`-parsing.